# Where will get Location Updates feature in XCode?

Tags: xcode, flutter, dart, location, google-geocoder

I can not show/get the "XCode project (Project > Signing and Capabilities > "+ Capability" button) and select the Location Updates" feature in my XCode.

it is in the link

https://pub.dev/packages/geolocator

On iOS you'll need to add the following entries to your Info.plist file (located under ios/Runner) in order to access the device's location. Simply open your Info.plist file and add the following (make sure you update the description so it is meaningfull in the context of your App):

```
<key>NSLocationWhenInUseUsageDescription</key>
<string>This app needs access to location when open.</string>
<key>NSLocationAlwaysUsageDescription</key>
<string>This app needs access to location when in the background.</string>
```

If you would like to receive updates when your App is in the background, you'll also need to add the Background Modes capability to your XCode project (Project > Signing and Capabilities > "+ Capability" button) and select Location Updates. Be careful with this, you will need to explain in detail to Apple why your App needs this when submitting your App to the AppStore. If Apple isn't satisfied with the explanation your App will be rejected.

When using the requestTemporaryFullAccuracy({purposeKey: "YourPurposeKey"}) method, a dictionary should be added to the Info.plist file.

```
<key>NSLocationTemporaryUsageDescriptionDictionary</key>
<dict>
  <key>YourPurposeKey</key>
  <string>The example App requires temporary access to the device&apos;s precise location.</string>
</dict>
```

The second key (in this example called YourPurposeKey) should match the purposeKey that is passed in the requestTemporaryFullAccuracy() method. It is possible to define multiple keys for different features in your app. More information can be found in Apple's documentation.

NOTE: The first time requesting temporary full accuracy access it might take several seconds for the pop-up to show. This is due to the fact that iOS is determining the exact user location which may take several seconds. Unfortunately, this is out of our hands.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you need to click + Capability then select background mode and then select location update
[image: here is an example of the location update selected]